# Not able to get specific pattern inside a string

Tags: c#, regex

I want to find a specific pattern of substring inside a string .Upto some extent  I can able to get but not exactly what i want to extract .

I am working on a  console application . Below i have mentioned the code

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string item = @"wewe=23213123i18n("""", test. ),cstr(12),i18n("""",test3)hdsghwgdhwsgd)"; 
            item = @"MsgBox(I18N(CStr(539)," + "Cannot migrate to the same panel type.)" +", MsgBoxStyle.Exclamation, DOWNLOAD_CAPTION)";
            string reg1 = @"i18n(.*),(.*)\)";
            string strVal = Regex.Match(item, reg1, RegexOptions.IgnorePatternWhitespace | RegexOptions.IgnoreCase).Groups[0].Value;
            List<string> str = new List<string> ();
            str.Add(strVal);
            System.IO.File.WriteAllLines(@"C:\Users\E543925.PACRIM1\Desktop\Tools\Test.txt", str);
        }
    }
}


Expected output -  I18N(CStr(539)," + "Cannot migrate to the same panel type.)
Actual output -  I18N(CStr(539),Cannot migrate to the samepaneltype.),MsgBoxStyle.Exclamation, DOWNLOAD_CAPTION)
```

I have to do some changes in regex expression . i tried , but not able to get success .
I am new to regex and c# .
Please help . 
Thanks in advance ..

Comment: I get `I18N(CStr(539),Cannot migrate to the same panel type.), MsgBoxStyle.Exclamation, DOWNLOAD_CAPTION)` as output. Could you verify actual and expected results

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to make the `.*` lazy (i.e. match as few characters as possible) with `.*?`
(or perhaps make your regex something like`"i18n\([^,)]*,[^)]*\)"` instead).

If you want multiple matches, so you should probably have a while-loop.

This:

```
string item = @"wewe=23213123i18n("""", test. ),cstr(12),i18n("""",test3)hdsghwgdhwsgd)"; 
item = @"MsgBox(I18N(CStr(539)," + "Cannot migrate to the same panel type.)" +", MsgBoxStyle.Exclamation, DOWNLOAD_CAPTION)";
string reg1 = @"i18n(.*?),(.*?)\)";
Match match = Regex.Match(item, reg1, RegexOptions.IgnorePatternWhitespace | RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
while (match.Success)
{
    string strVal = match.Groups[0].Value;
    Console.WriteLine(strVal);
    match = match.NextMatch();
}
```

Prints:

```
I18N(CStr(539),Cannot migrate to the same panel type.)
```

[Live demo](https://ideone.com/Qix2ie).

Answer (score 0):

you can try this regex:

```
i18n(\([^\)]*\))
```

it means: match i18n and capture groups that start with an open (, are followed by any character except a closed ) and then have a closed )